# Named and Default Instances on single SQL Cluster

Tags: sql-server

current environment we have Server A and Server B - WFCS with Default instance serving applications(SQL 2012) Now we want move a named instance (SQL 2008) to the above cluster.

What will be the consequences if I create a Named instance on the above existing setup. will the idea work ?

If yes,

do we need separate IP in the same VLAN for named instance and add it to cluster resources ? Also will fail-over happen as before ?

Suggestions pls

Comment: You should not install unsupported software into an existing supported environment.  If you must run SQL 2008, install it in an isolated VM somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

> What will be the consequences if I create a Named instance on the above existing setup. will the idea work ?

It should work like any other instance. Lot of people have multiple instances of SQL FCI running peacefully.

> do we need separate IP in the same VLAN for named instance and add it to cluster resources ? Also will fail-over happen as before ?

Yes, you would need a separate IP, which will be used for virtual network name. You would also need separate storage for the new SQL FCI. They all can use same network though. Failover should  work just fine and manually you would have control to just failover the FCI you like.